# VBA: Filling blank cells with the value above it plus one

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 sheets which have blank cells and I need to fill them up with the value above plus 1. For example: column A has 1,2, ,4,5 and I need a code that will make it 1,2,3,4,5

I have tried a code I found online but it just copies the value above it.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

I need to fill all the blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program would be simpler, faster, and *more efficient* by avoiding the use of `Select` as much as possible. Here is a correct program in one line:

```vb
Sub FillBlanks()
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
End Sub
```

**To apply to all 5 sheets in your workbook:**

```vb
Sub FillBlanks()
Dim ws as Worksheet, LastRow as Long
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without VBA.

Select the range, hit F5 to open the Go To dialog, click **Special** and in the next dialog tick **Blanks** and click OK. That will select all blank cells in the selected range.

Now, without changing the selection, type a `=` sign, then hit the **up arrow** on the keyboard, then type `+1`. Hold down the **Ctrl** key and hit **Enter**.

[image]

If you still want to use VBA, change the last line of code to

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
```

That will give you the same result as the manual approach.